# App doesn't run. Getting error window

Tags: android

I have a problem with this code. This is a tutorial code that show how to get and show data from mysql DB. But when I try to run it I am getting a problem window that application has stopped unexpectedly. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
public class FoodActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String result = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    StringBuilder sbuilder = null;
    ArrayList <NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("1","Avinas"));

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ik.su.lt/~jbarzelis/Bandymas/index.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        input = entity.getContent();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error in internet connection"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sbuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sbuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        input.close();
        result = sbuilder.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());          
    }
    int fd_id;
    String fd_name;
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            fd_id = json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
            fd_name = json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
        }

        }
    catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No food found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The application Food has stopped unexpectedly. please try again. This is what i get when app starts in the simulator.

Comment: post logcat error. This message doesn't help in resolving the issue.

Comment: First of many error:02-29 22:43:41.311: ERROR/log_tag(427): Error in internet connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: ik.su.lt

Comment: 02-29 22:43:41.311: ERROR/log_tag(427): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException, are you able to access this url from browser?

Comment: @Shien: `UnknownHostException` - basically it looks like it's unable to resolve the address `ik.su.lt` which will mean everything will fail after that. Make sure your connection has valid (and reachable) DNS servers configured and you're not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: I can access it from browser. @MisterSqounk what do you mean by DNS configurations? You mean on the server side?

Comment: @Shien: An 'unknown host' situation will usually mean the client can't access a DNS server to perform an IP address lookup or the DNS server is reachable but doesn't have access to lookup the IP address. The fact you say you can access it with a browser suggests that's not the problem. Have you specified the permission to access the internet in your manifest? That would normally throw a different error though if you haven't.

Comment: No. I have't specified anything in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` before the opening `<application` element...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**EDIT:**

The reason you're getting warnings about fd_id and fd_name never being read is because they never are. All you do in this code...

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    fd_id = json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
    fd_name = json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
}
```

...is parse the JSON array using those variables (fd_id and fd_name) but you never do anything with them and there's no more code after that block (except for the catch blocks which do nothing unless there's an exception).

Try logging those variables as follows...

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    fd_id = json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
    fd_name = json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
    Log.d("XYZ", "fd_id: " + fd_id);
    Log.d("XYZ", "fd_name: " + fd_name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not getting this error anymore. But now I am not getting any data form DB. The app shows Hello World FoodActivity.

Comment: There is warning that fd_id and fd_name is never read. how to fix it?

Comment: I can't anything with XYZ starting

Comment: I am getting exception that no food is found.

Comment: <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","****","********");
 mysql_select_db("test");
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from FOOD where FOOD_NAME like 'A%'");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close;
?>

Comment: This is php script that  I am using to get data from DB

Comment: Sorry, not good with php - I expect it's how you're reading the response. I'd suggest posting a new question now you're no longer getting the problem with the internet permission.

Answer (score 0):

For the error

> "error:02-29 22:43:41.311: ERROR/log_tag(427): Error in internet
>   connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: ik.su.lt"

can you please check if you have

a. Asked for permission to access the internet in the android manifest file as per the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

b. If you can browse a website from the android browser in the emulator

The second error

> Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

comes from the catch statement

```
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());          
}
```

which occurs because variable 'input' in the try block is null because you do not have the internet permission as mentioned above. So basically solving the internet permission should fix all your issues.